# Error while deleting data from table (self referencing table with parent-child relation) in spring jpa

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity class name comments which have hierarchy relation with itself.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "comment")
public class Comment implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "document", nullable = false)
    private Document document;

    @Column(name = "threadid")
    private String threadId;

    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "content")
    private String content;

    @Column(name = "authorid")
    private String authorId;

    @Column(name = "timestamp")
    private String timeStamp;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentcomment")
    private ContractComment parentComment;
}
```

I want to delete all the comments for a document, but when I use the following query using JpaRepository

```
"delete from Comment where document.id = :documentId"
```

It gives the following error.

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`comment`, CONSTRAINT `fk_comment_parentcomment` FOREIGN KEY (`parentcomment`) REFERENCES `comment` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

I tried these 3 methods, but always got same error.

```
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentcomment")
    private ContractComment parentComment;



    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentcomment")
    private ContractComment parentComment;


    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentcomment")
    private ContractComment parentComment;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)`
 not `@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType=REMOVE)`

Comment: just to point out the difference: it's `CascadeType.REMOVE` (with a **.** ) not `CascadeType=REMOVE`.

Comment: I am using this (CascadeType.REOVE) in program but I typed here wrong. I am correcting it in my question. But It's not working.

Comment: Can you add another constraint like this? `value = { CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE }` or try `CascadeType.ALL`

Answer (score 1):

Use the CriteriaQueries to handle your entities not direct JPQL queries. 
A CriteriaQuery could look like this:

```
public void deleteComments(Long documentId) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = this.em.getCriteriaBuilder();

    // create delete
    CriteriaDelete<Comment> delete = cb.
     createCriteriaDelete(Comment.class);

    // set the root class
    Root root = delete.from(Comment.class);

    // set where clause
    delete.where(cb.equal(root.get(Comment_.document).get(Document_.id), documentId));

    // perform update
    this.em.createQuery(delete).executeUpdate();
}
```

The `Comment_` class can be used to get all "columns" of your "Comment" entities, so first you get the Documents from your Comments (`root.get(Comment_.document)`) then you get the document's id (`...get(Document_.id)`) and compare it with your parameter.

Criteria Queries are a bit different from JPQL strings, but they have the advantage that the compiler helps you implement changes in your database (while JPQL queries just throw runtime errors)

If you don't want to use a query like this you can always implement a `deleteComments` method in you `Document` class. Then you fetch the Document and let the entityManager handle the deletion:

```
Document doc = entityManager.find(Document.class, documentId);

// and in the Document class:
public void deleteComments(){
    this.comments.stream.forEach( comment-> comment.delete());
}
```

Comment: I tried using criteria query but it is giving the same error.